# Create multidimensional array from txt file

Tags: php

txt file that looks like this:

```
first item1:second item1:third item1:fourth item1:fifth item1
first item2:second item2:third item2:fourth item2:fifth item2
first item3:second item3:third item3:fourth item3:fifth item3
```

I want to be able to output each item sperately.

As far as I see it, I need to:

- open the file with `file()`
- create a multidimensional array, by first splitting up the lines
- use `explode()` to split it up by `:`

I have tried various things but I can't get it to work. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: You say you've tried various things.  Can you supply the example you think is closest to working?

Comment: Use `file()` to read the file into a standard array, then [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) that array using a callback that does the explode() on `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need something like this?

```
$lines = file('try.txt');
$output = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $output[] =  array_map(function($var) { 
        return rtrim($var, "\r\n");
    }, explode(":", $line));

}
var_dump($output);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'first item1' (length=11)
      1 => string 'second item1' (length=12)
      2 => string 'third item1' (length=11)
      3 => string 'fourth item1' (length=12)
      4 => string 'fifth item1' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'first item2' (length=11)
      1 => string 'second item2' (length=12)
      2 => string 'third item2' (length=11)
      3 => string 'fourth item2' (length=12)
      4 => string 'fifth item2' (length=11)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'first item3' (length=11)
      1 => string 'second item3' (length=12)
      2 => string 'third item3' (length=11)
      3 => string 'fourth item3' (length=12)
      4 => string 'fifth item3' (length=11)
```

Comment: Way too much effort for someone with such questions ;)

Comment: We are here to helping each others. I was beginner too :) You are welcome.